# Django: Is it possible to make a `forms.HiddenInput` mandatory?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I have 9 hidden radio buttons in a survey form each with an attached **visible** image. The idea is that the user should select one of the images before they move onto the next page of the survey. The application will then store the name of the submitted image.

If possible I would like to make the `forms.HiddenInput` mandatory so that the user **has** to select one of the images before they can proceed to the next page

I understand that this sounds like a bit of a silly question but does anybody know if this is possible and how to do it? Thanks

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormDV4(forms.ModelForm):       

    class Meta:  
        model = Person
        fields = ['DV_positive']
        widgets = {'DV_positive' : forms.HiddenInput}
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ....
    ....

    DV_positive = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self
```

NOTE: If I do not pass `blank=True` here the page will not submit whether I pick an option of not.

**views.py**

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                             
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                      
        step = int(self.steps.current)   

            ....

            ....

            elif step == 22:

                context.update({'first_image' : images[0],
                           'second_image' : images[1],
                           'third_image' : images[2],
                           ....
                           .... 
                           })
```

**wizard_form.html**

```
    {% if wizard.steps.current in dv_nine_positive %}

                                <div id="dialog-message" title="Positive Bias">
                                    <p>
                                        Please select your favorite image
                                    </p>

                                </div>          
                                  <script>
                                    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                                      autoOpen: true,
                                      modal: true,
                                      buttons: {
                                        Ok: function() {
                                          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                        }
                                      }
                                    });
                                    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                                        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                                    });
                                  </script>

                            <div class="DV_image_row">                                      
                                <div class="DV_image_left">
                                    <label class="radio_hidden">        
                                    <input type="radio" name="final_dv" value="1"/>
                                        <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{first_image}}" height="300" width="250"/>                          
                                    </label>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="DV_image_centre">                                       
                                    <label class="radio_hidden">            
                                    <input type="radio" name="final_dv" value="2"/>
                                        <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{second_image}}" height="300" width="250"/>                         
                                    </label>                
                                </div>
                                <div class="DV_image_right">                                        
                                    <label class="radio_hidden">        
                                    <input type="radio" name="final_dv" value="3"/>
                                        <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{third_image}}" height="300" width="250"/>                          
                                    </label>                                
                                </div>
                            </div>                      
                            <div class="DV_image_row">                                      
                                <div class="DV_image_left">                                                                                     

                         ....

                         ....





                    <div class="submit_buttons">
                        {% if wizard.steps.prev %}                      
                            <button class="btn" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "First Step" %}</button>
                            <button class="btn" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Prev Step" %}</button>
                        {% endif %}             
                        <input class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "Next" %}"/>
                    </div>





                        {% endif %}
```

Comment: How does this field get its value? I see no js logic in there for that. Also, where is the `{{ DV_positive }}` field in your template?

Comment: It is not necessary to put a `{{ DV_positive }}` field in the form as the SessionWizardView takes all of the fields and renders them through a `{{ form }}` tag. The `{% if wizard.steps.current in dv_nine_positive %}` is the logic to decide if the 9 images are to be dispalyed